# how to get forms next to each other rather than below one another

Tags: css

i have a form below i m trying to apply class to it so that forms are next to each other rather than one below the other but its not working

below is my code

```
 <form action="" method="POST">
     <div class="imgthumb"><?php the_post_thumbnail('thumbnail'); ?></div>
     <div class="votebtn">
        <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $postid; ?>" name="id" />
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Vote" />
      </div?    
     <div class="votecounttxt"><?php echo $votecount; ?></div>             
 </form>
```

u caa see it live at http://myproject.byethost7.com/?page_id=5

Comment: In you example none of the forms or divs have classes applied.

Comment: What CSS have you tried already? There is no form on the link you provided.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of approaches, either change the `display` for the `form` or use a `float`, in this instance:

```
form {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Should do it for you. Your forms are currently displaying as `block` content, taking up an entire 'line' instead of simply the width of their content and allowing subsequent content to 'flow' after it on the same line. Changing to `inline-block` will change them to do this. Floating works in a similar way from a visual perspective, however may have unforseen consequences so is likely not necessary here.

Comment: where do i put it? when i put it in style.css it does nothing

Comment: The link provided has no style.css, nor indeed correct HTML page structure. As such, without the actual context in which the code is being used it is very difficult / impossible to say what you need to do. Try changing the above to use e.g. `.inlineForm` instead of `form` then giving each form `class="inlineForm"` in your CSS

Comment: currently the form uses the user agent stylesheet how do i get that changed so it reads style.css

Comment: the code is a page template for a page in wordpress

Answer (score 0):

ok i got it i just had to include the styles css directly in the template...since template didn't have getheader the stylesheet was not getting loaded

Comment: This is an attempt at a self-answer.